Computing an exact range with FunctionRange
When using FunctionRange to compute the range of the two-argument ArcTan function, Mathematica fails to return an exact answer.
FunctionRange[ArcTan[x, y], {x, y}, t]

(*FunctionRange::nopt: Unable to find the exact range. Returning bounds on the range computed using numeric optimization methods.*)

(*-3.14159 <= t <= 3.14159*)

I observe that one can use ComplexExpand to turn two-argument ArcTan into the complex Arg function, but this doesn't seem to help, as in that case it stays unevaluated after throwing a message.
ArcTan[x, y] // ComplexExpand

(*Arg[x + I y]*)

FunctionRange[Arg[z], z, t, Complexes]

(*FunctionRange::nmet: Unable to find the range with the available methods.*)

(*FunctionRange[Arg[z], z, t, Complexes]*)

It would be convenient for me to have a generic method that wouldn't require me to "cheat" by supplying the range of ArcTan manually. I carefully read the documentation for the functions involved, but wasn't able to deduce the right way to proceed. Any help appreciated!

FunctionRange[ArcTan[x, y], {x, y}, t, Method -> {"Reduced" -> True}] gives an exact answer, although I can't say like it.

Thanks for the observation. That is rather ugly. I'll see if I can find a way to coerce that into something usable.

Reduce[ArcTan[x, y] == -Pi, {x, y}, Reals] results in False so the range is t>-Pi&&t<=Pi.

It was noted that FunctionRange can give an exact answer, but in a very complex form that I wasn't able to manipulate fruitfully. In the absence of a better solution, I employed the following function to recognize explicit numerical pi up to a tolerance.
recognizePi[expr_] :=
 expr /.
  x_Real /; Abs[x] - Pi < 10^-10 :>
   Sign[x]*Pi

FunctionRange[ArcTan[x, y], {x, y}, t] // Quiet // recognizePi

(* -π <= t <= π *)


FunctionRange[ArcTan[x, y], {x, y}, t] /. r_Real :> RootApproximant[r/Pi]*Pi will also handle multiples of Pi

Thank you very much! That is much better.

Unfortunately, Reduce[ArcTan[x, y] == -Pi, {x, y}, Reals] results in False.
